# Functional equivalent in pandas to assigning one or more elements in a series

Tags: python, pandas

I am wondering if there is a functional but efficient equivalent to the following mutative code:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(...)
s[k] = v   # I don't want to mutate s
```

so that the operation returns a new series `s2` with the mutation. I can use `copy()` and then mutate; for example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

t = np.arange(100)
s = pd.Series(t*t,t)
s2 = s.copy()
s2[[3,4]] = [44,55]
s2
```

but is there a way to do it in one swoop and return a new Series without changing the existing series, like with `apply` or `map` or `replace`... but here I know the indices and the values I want to change.

Comment: It seems this is why pandas has its `SettingWithCopy` warning, writing code that creates a copy and modifies it in one go is going to leave the next person who looks at it wondering what exactly the code is doing. `copy` and assign makes it obvious what is actually happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a straightforward method to do this. Your copy+assign approach is actually fine (this is what I would do, and a common trick in [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy))

`map`, `apply` and `replace` consider the values, not the indices.

The easiest that comes to my mind for a functional approach would be to craft a Series with the indices and values to replace and to [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

```
pd.Series([44, 55], index=[3, 4]).combine_first(s)
```

And if you need this in a pipeline:

```
s2 = (pd.Series(t*t,t)
        .pipe(pd.Series([44, 55], index=[3, 4]).combine_first)
       #.other(...)
     )
```

Output:

```
0     0
1     1
2     4
3    44
4    55
5    25
6    36
7    49
8    64
9    81
...
dtype: int64
```